# OpenCV how to put jpeg image buffer to cvShowImage

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a JPG image in buffer and I would try to show it with cvShowImage. This is not working, however:

```
// buff is a JPEG image with 640*480 dimensions

IplImage* fIplImageHeader;
fIplImageHeader = cvCreateImageHeader(cvSize(640, 480), 8, 1);
fIplImageHeader->imageData = (char *)buff;

cvShowImage("Window 1", fIplImageHeader);
cvWaitKey();

cvReleaseImageHeader(&fIplImageHeader);
```

I get a black window with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to set [widthStep](http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html#SECTION00040000000000000000)

```
  |-- int  widthStep;     // size of aligned image row in bytes
  |-- int  imageSize;     // image data size in bytes = height*widthStep
```

Comment: also it could be the pointer is empty... try to copy the data like this guy did... http://umanga.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-to-covert-qt-qimage-into-opencv-iplimage-and-wise-versa/

Comment: you may also need to change cvCreateImageHeader(cvSize(640, 480), 8, 1); to cvCreateImageHeader(cvSize(640, 480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

Comment: I tried setting width and height. No help. I still get a black window... just with a white blurry line on top. The pointer is not empty. I checked that every frame has around 30KB.

Comment: I think I have found an issue. The cvCreateImageHeader creates an image that is 300KB large from a 30KB large JPG image in buffer. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261861/jpg-image-goes-from-30kb-to-300kb-after-cvcreateimageheader